# How can I import demo content of a theme in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I've recently purchased a WordPress theme from themeforest, how can I get the actual view or same layout that I've seen on the "Live Preview" page at themeforest. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you purchase a theme from Themeforest you also get a documentation download that provides straightforward instructions for using your theme within WordPress. If you did not download the docs then you should do so...

Answer (score 0):

which theme you have purchased  ?
You can find mysql database inside the folder import that database in your db and put all the file in wordpress root directory.